# Blockchain.info block explorer error: Transaction rejected by our node. Reason: None Standard Script Output OP_RETURN 4f410100010100

Tags: blockchain.info, colored-coins, blockexplorer

Searching for a specific colored coin transaction on the blockchain.info block explorer yields this error:

Transaction rejected by our node. Reason: None Standard Script Output OP_RETURN 4f410100010100

Any ideas? I thought colored tx ideas should be searchable, especially with a standard tx fee attached to it.

Comment: This is a problem with the service, try contacting their [support](https://blockchain.zendesk.com/).